# How to sort numbers from smallest to largest in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sort my array of numbers from smallest to largest WITHOUT using the built-in `sort()` method.

Here's what I have:

```
def sort my_numbers
  new_array = []
  my_numbers.each() do | number|
    first = new_array.push(my_numbers.min)
    last = new_array.push(my_numbers.max)
    range_of_numbers = (first..last)

    if range_of_numbers.include?(number)
      new_array.push(number)
    end
    return new_array
  end
end


puts sort([5, 9, 2, 5, 2])
```

This gives me `[2, 9]` but I want those middle numbers too. I tried using a range from my first and last numbers in my array and comparing that range with my array to see if it contained numbers from my array.

Comment: also in irb it says it can't iterate the array

Comment: The problem is that `first` and `last` are Arrays, whereas the range is expecting Integers. Please could you explain what you want them to contain?

Comment: Is there any particular sorting algorithm you're trying to implement?

Comment: The biggest problem is that mathematically speaking, your sort cannot work this way. If the next number is between min and max, you don't know exactly at which index it should be inserted. The closest, working algorithm you could write is probably an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: Don't apologize for being new to programming or a language. We only care whether you've done your research and whether you've asked your question clearly and concisely. Please read Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and the pages he links to to understand what we need and how to ask.

Comment: @SekalfNroc ahhh that makes sense!

Comment: @SekalfNroc No I was just trying to find the next number in the array and somehow add it after my lowest number in my array. Could I add the method to_i on first and last?

Comment: `arr = [5, 9, 2, 5, 2]; arr.min(arr.size) #=> [2, 2, 5, 5, 9]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Nice try. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Wow thanks man! never knew .size existed!

Comment: `Enumerable` methods `min`, `max`, `min_by` and `max_by` have accepted an argument since Ruby V2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something *similar* to work.

```
def sort my_numbers
  remaining_numbers = my_numbers.dup               # Don't change the original
  new_array = []
  my_numbers.each do
    number = remaining_numbers.min                 # Get smallest
    index = remaining_numbers.find_index number    # Find it's index
    remaining_numbers.delete_at index              # Delete at that index

    new_array.push(number)                         # Add it to the sorted array
  end

  return new_array
end

puts sort([5, 9, 2, 5, 2])
```

It works by finding the smallest unsorted number and appending it to `new_array`. The number is then deleted from the array of remaining numbers. It repeats this until no numbers remain.